# How often should I use the battery on my MacBook (which I exclusively use as desktop)?

Tags: battery

Since getting my mb-pro 3 years ago, I've only used it as a desktop. A few times, the battery has kicked-in for a few hours while the power was out. Someday, I might want to task it as a laptop. *For the sake of the battery* :

> Should I be unplugging my mb from the wall just to use the battery?
>   For how long should I run on battery?
>   How often should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from https://web.archive.org/web/20110521104819/http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html

> **Standard Maintenance**
>   For proper maintenance of a lithium-based
>   battery, it’s important to keep the electrons in it moving
>   occasionally. Apple does not recommend leaving your portable plugged
>   in all the time. An ideal use would be a commuter who uses her
>   notebook on the train, then plugs it in at the office to charge. This
>   keeps the battery juices flowing. If on the other hand, you use a
>   desktop computer at work, and save a notebook for infrequent travel,
>   Apple recommends charging and discharging its battery at least once
>   per month. Need a reminder? Add an event to your desktop’s iCal. When
>   your battery no longer holds sufficient charge to meet your needs, you
>   may choose to replace it. If your notebook came with a built-in
>   battery, you should have the battery replaced only by an Apple
>   Authorized Service Provider.

Comment: I thought as much... Just started testing it with a 2 (usb3) drives attached under minimal usage. 28" monitor also attached, but that should not use my battery at all I think. I'm hoping for 8-hours.